# Possible to run Docker Desktop for Windows on a VPS?

Tags: windows, docker, vps

I tried installing Docker Desktop version 3.5.2 (newer Docker version not possible due to Windows 1809) on a Windows Server 2019 Virtual Private Server (VPS), but the server crashes all the time. I get this response from the hosting company: the customer is using WSL2, which uses hyper-v as a type-1 hypervisor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq). As of now, we do not recommend using nested virtualization in our environment.

Is it possible to run Docker Desktop for Windows on a VPS?

Comment: Their virtualization software doesn't support Hyper-V on top of their system, either change to bare metal product or switch to other provider

Comment: Thanks, in other words you are saying that there are VPS providers that would support Hyper-V on top of their system? It's not related to the fact it's installed on a VPS?

Comment: Yep https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/ likely more expensive but if that's what you need (instead of just using docker on Linux), then that's your only option.